# Disabling Hibernation Boot on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, grub, initramfs, hibernate

i recently installed Debian 10 Buster with KDE Plasma Desktop to my laptop. When i logon, system starts up the apps while they were open before shutdown.

I edited the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
as `RESUME=none` and ran sudo update-initramfs, but Debian still resuming from disk when i restarted my computer.

Also i have no kernel parameter like `resume=UUIDblabla` in `/etc/default/grub` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a feature of KDE. It'll restart applications that were previously open in the last session.

Go to:
[System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Session Management](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Startup_and_Shutdown#Session_Management)
and select something other than "Restore previous session".

You'll probably want to re-enable hibernation.

Comment: Thanks! When i reboot i see only KDE apps keep resume. I thought it maybe a KDE feature after i asked the question :)